# Separar e juntar arrays

Tags: php

tenho o seguinte array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [setor_loja] => 43
            [impressao] =>  (P) Pizza 2 + Pizza 2\n
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [setor_loja] => 83
            [impressao] => Acai 300 ml\n
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [setor_loja] => 83
            [impressao] => AA§ai 500 ml\n
        )

)
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [setor_loja] => 33
            [impressao] => Misto c/ ovo\n
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [setor_loja] => 33
            [impressao] => Misto duplo\n
        )

)
```

Gostaria que a saída ficasse assim:
(P) Pizza 2 + Pizza 2\n ( sair sozinho )

Acai 300 ml\n + Açai 500 ml\n ( sair junto pois esses dois produtos são do mesmo setor)

Misto c/ ovo\n + Misto duplo\n ( sair junto pois esses dois produtos são do mesmo setor)

Comment: Sugiro formatar o array de saída da mesma forma que o de entrada, para que fique mais claro.

Comment: E o seu código? Parece que você esqueceu de postá-lo.

Comment: vc quer apenas concatenar a saida ou gerar um novo array com todos os elementos do setor?

Comment: Como você está gerando esse `array`? A organização dos índices dele estão em sequência porém mesmo assim são `arrays` distintos com produtos diferentes.

Comment: Oi rray, apenas concatenar a saída, dai eu me viro.
Oi Marcelo, esse array está vindo de uma série de foreachs e selects pra monta-lo, um pedaço do código é esse: $dados[] = array(
                'setor_loja'=>$setor_setor.$setor_loja,
                'impressao'=>''
                . $produto.'\n'
                );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Montei uma combinação que cria uma novo array com todos os produtos/itens agrupo pelo código da loja.

`array_column()` extrair todos ids das lojas, `array_flip()` inverter os valores com as chaves do array retornado pelo `array_column()` sua saida é algo como:

```
Array
(
    [43] => 0
    [83] => 2
    [33] => 4
)
```

Depois é feita uma verificação se array de 'produtos' se existe o id da loja ele copia a descrição do produto e joga em um novo elemento.

```
$arr = array(
        array('setor_loja' => '43', 'impressao' => '(P) Pizza 2 + Pizza 2\n'),
        array('setor_loja' => '83', 'impressao' => 'Acai 300 ml\n'),
        array('setor_loja' => '83', 'impressao' => 'Açai 500 ml\n'),
        array('setor_loja' => '33', 'impressao' => 'Misto c/ ovo\n'),
        array('setor_loja' => '33', 'impressao' => 'Misto duplo\n')
);


$setores = array_flip(array_column($arr, 'setor_loja'));
$novo = array();
foreach($arr as $item){
    if(isset($setores[$item['setor_loja']])){
        $novo[$item['setor_loja']][] = $item['impressao'];
    }
}
```

A saida de `$novo` é:

```
Array
(
    [43] => Array
        (
            [0] => (P) Pizza 2 + Pizza 2\n
        )

    [83] => Array
        (
            [0] => Acai 300 ml\n
            [1] => Açai 500 ml\n
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => Misto c/ ovo\n
            [1] => Misto duplo\n
        )

)
```

Para exibir dos os produtos de uma loja pode usar a função `implode()`:

```
echo 'Loja 33 '. implode(' | ', $novo[33]);
```

Saida:

```
Loja 33 Misto c/ ovo\n | Misto duplo\n
```

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos que responderam, e a vc meu amigo! consegui implementar meu sistema com essa solução.